# Exception while displaying Runtime permission dialog

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to show the READ_PHONE_STATE dialog but getting the following exception

```
 GrantPermissionsActivity: No package: null
 android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:254)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:239)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.getCallingPackageInfo(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:350)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.onCreate(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:101)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I have declared the permission in my manifest file and using the following code to display the permission dialog.

```
public void requestPermission(Activity activity, String[] permission, int permissionRequestCode) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity, permission[0])) {
            // todo : show some message here
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permission, permissionRequestCode);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permission, permissionRequestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what is the problem here. Earlier it was working fine but since I moved the logic to somewhere else it stopped working. Please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33219034/6891563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

The reason why I was getting this exception is because the activity reference that I was passing to `requestPermission` method is null i.e., the activity has actually finished before I was requesting the permission and hence I was getting that exception.

So make sure that the activity/fragment instance that you are passing to `requestPermission` is not null.

Hope this helps.